# Java ProcessBuilder redirectInput with cat

Tags: java, processbuilder, cat

I am writing a Java application that needs to execute the unix `cat` command using ProcessBuilder. I know I can use the arguments to the ProcessBuilder object to specify the file for `cat` to use. However, to standardize the interface, how would I use redirectInput() instead to pass the input file?

I'm assuming this would work as I can perform `cat < foo.txt` in the command line, which is equivalent to redirectInput() in ProcessBuilder (right?)

Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just try it?

I've written a simple test code:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cat")
    .redirectInput(new File("/tmp/test", "i.txt"))
    .redirectOutput(new File("/tmp/test", "o.txt"))
    .start()
    .waitFor();
```

And it successfully copied some text from `i.txt` to `o.txt`.